# Spark 1.0.1 and HDP 2 - How to connect via ODBC?

Tags: odbc, hive, apache-spark

I'm trying to connect with the Simba ODBC Shark Connector to my instance of Spark 1.0.1. When Shark was a standalone project, I was able to connect to it without any problem. Right now I'm having an hard time with this new Spark release because I suppose that Shark has been integrated inside Spark but I have no idea how to talk to it, especially because I don't know on which port it is listening to.

Actually I only managed to connect successfully to Hive(that is listening on port 10000
) with the HortonWorks ODBC connector.

Does anyone could give me an hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the while, only the SAP version of Spark 1.0.1 includes the ThriftServer that you need to use Thrift/JDBC/ODBC.

http://www.saphana.com/docs/DOC-4721

The next dot release of Spark--1.1--will incorporate the ThriftServer.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2410

George

Comment: Spark 1.1 should be released really soon; according to our current [release window](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Wiki+Homepage), release candidates will be released and voting will start on on August 15.  The JDBC connector was actually merged yesterday (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/1620), so you can download and build the master branch if you want to try it out now.